# Run system tests against deployed app with Nancy.Testing

Tags: nancy, system-testing

I've successfully set up some tests that run complete use cases against our code base using nancy.testing.

Now I'd like to use the same tests for what we call release tests: We deploy the complete application to a staging server and run the system tests against it. We already use that approach successfully with a WCF application.

Is there an easy way to make this work? I've noticed that `Browser` and `BrowserResponse` do not use any abstractions, so I cannot replace them with a `SystemTestBrowser` or similar.

I could of course abstract the whole nancy.testing package away, but I thought I ask here first if someone knows a simpler approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Nancy.Testing` does not use any network communication at all. If you can think of a nice abstract then please let us know and we can talk and see if it's something we'd like to get into the package!

Comment: I think a ``Browser`` and ``BrowserResponse`` that are agnostic to the test target (be it an in-process Nancy app or a deployed one) would serve well. I suppose that testing a deployed app is even much simpler, because the test does not need to instantiate the whole application.